# Best practice for using API

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I have some CRUD controllers set up in my project like this:

```
var getMaps = function (req, res) {
    Map.find({}).exec(function (err, collections) {
        res.send(collections);
    });
};
```

In order to use these in the server side code, I've been using node's http.get like this:

```
var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3030,
    path: '/api/map'
};

http.get(options, function (res) {
    var data = '';
    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    }).on('end', function () {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
    });
}).on('error', function (e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

where my routes file contains

```
app.get('/api/map', map.getMaps);
```

Is this the correct way of doing it? It seems like it would be slow since it is an http request but I don't know any other way to do it

Comment: Are you using REST API to comunicate backend with backend?

Answer (score -1):

Better you go through [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) links once to have a better understanding of angular's APIs.
You can also try out the MEANs CRUD module which comes by default when you generate a MEAN application.

Comment: I know Angulars api and how to use $http and $resource, that was not my question. I'm using the api from the backend code as well (node/express not angular) and I don't know if there's a more efficient  way of doing it